# Rest Api Link build

Tags: android, api

I have made a rest api with database for an Android app. I have made this in php in my localhost. Now I want to access it from my Android app. How can I access it through URL in internet. I am totally new to this, plz give me in details.

Comment: I suggest that you use Retrofit.

Comment: which server you are using?

Comment: You also need to host your API on a computer with a publicly available IP and/or DNS record.

Comment: all of my api components  is in my computer localhost. I want the this api on live server and make a link to access through Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question, brings back so much memories. You need to tunnel your local host packets to the public internet. There are many tools, but the main one i use is `NgRok`.

Details

1. Test mobile apps against a development backend running on your machine. Point ngrok at your local dev server and then configure your app to use the ngrok URL. It won't change, even when you change networks.
2. Don’t constantly redeploy your in-progress work to get feedback from clients. ngrok creates a secure public URL (https://yourapp.ngrok.io) to a local webserver on your machine. Iterate quickly with immediate feedback without interrupting flow.

A note of interest. if your app currently as a https signed certificate you might need to add some extra classes, if not you good to go. [Read up here.](https://ngrok.com/)

Guide lines for local public hosting.

- Create your webserver(php,node.js etc) , start it, and verify on localhost:port
- Start ngrok, its simple visit the website, the instructions are there
- Ngrok will give you a url, that url is public anyone can access it, while your computer is powered on
- On android side, use a http client, such as Volley, Http2 or Retrofit.
- You have a few reading up to do

Comment: I also suggest using Retrofit to make the http requests to your server, A type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java. The best in the game for me and many others

Comment: This method is cheap, no money, instead of paying for public hosting,

Comment: can you please tell me step by step. I only have a simple api with database in my computer.